# gdalwarp crop_to_cutline generates error for some states

Tags: ogr2ogr, gdalwarp, population

I am trying to crop states of a country by using `gdalwarp` . For some of the states I get this particular error, while for other states it runs fine. This is my second day at GIS/gdalwarp, so please pardon my naiveness. As of now, I do not know anything about shapefiles or geojson (other than how to view them)

Here is the sequence of commands:

```
#Reprojecting the world population obtained from NASA:    
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 shapefiles/World/gpw2000.tif inter/repropop2000.tif

#Reprojecting the shapefile containing states of a country (India)
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 India/reproj.shp  India/India_state.shp

#Creating geojson for a particular state
ogr2ogr -f geojson India/state1671.geojson India/reproj.shp -sql "SELECT * FROM reproj WHERE state_id = '1671'"

#Cutting the map
gdalwarp -crop_to_cutline -overwrite -cutline India/state1671.geojson repropop2000.tif lastcut.tif
Warning 1: Too few points in geometry component at or near point 82.551917767195008 19.199543505051185
ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
```

I am using SRS EPSG = 4326. I believe tifs should be fine as the last command works for some other states.

Let me know if I need to attach any of the files.

Comment: Are you sure those input files have a proper source CRS? Otherwise reprojection will change nothing. You might try a GIS software like QGIS to see if your layers align. Visualization makes things a lot easier for newbies.